# Group windows on the dash (MATLAB figures)

Tags: 14.04, gnome, matlab, dock

Does anyone know how to get gnome to recognize the figures matlab generates as groupable? I have to create quite a lot of figures and the dash is starting to get really small. It groups everything else perfectly except MATLAB.

[image: small dash]

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04 (with Unity) machine, the MATLAB figures are grouped. Do you still see this problem in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I'm going to buy a new laptop sometime next week and I'll install ubuntu 16.04 on it. On computers that I HAVE to use every day I use a LTS release until it's end of life so I haven't installed 16.04 yet. I'll let you know once I've checked. It could also be due to gnome's grouping algorithm but I'll let you know